# Installing from .deb files in macOS Catalina

Tags: install, catalina, homebrew, package-management

I tried installing dpkg with brew. When it was done installing, it gave me the following message :-

**==> Caveats
This installation of dpkg is not configured to install software, so
commands such as `dpkg -i`, `dpkg --configure` will fail.**

Since dpkg -i is used to install packages, I need some help to fix this.

Also, are there any other ways to install .deb packages in MacOS? I'm open to using other methods as well

Thanks in advance

Comment: where can I find a test file ?

Comment: .deb files are built/ compiled for Linux, how do you want to run them on macOS?

Answer (score 3):

As far I know, a .deb file is a packaged software installer for Debian Linux (and its derivatives.)

If you want to install it, you're out of luck. I don't think there is anyway to install .deb packages on OS X.

However, we can unpack a .deb file on Mac OS X without installing it.

If you use Xcode, a utility called ar is installed. You can run the following command:

```
ar -x path/to/filename.deb
```

Alternatively, you could use Homebrew to install the dpkg utility which has many more options to work against .deb files.

```
dpkg -c path/to/filename.deb
```